# Ajax.BeginForm search not calling method in Controller (MVC 4)

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

my Ajax.BeginForm isn't submitting the search criteria to the controller. The code is as follows:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index_AddSearchCriteria", "Home", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "SearchDiv" }))
{

       // @Html.Label("Search: ") // should I use this instead?
       // @Html.TextBox("search_criteria") // should I use this instead?
       <input type="text" name="search_criteria" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<div id="SearchDiv">

</div>
```

and in the controller

```
    public PartialViewResult Index_AddSearchCriteria(string search_criteria)
    {
        ViewModel.SearchCriteria = search_criteria;

        return PartialView("SearchBar", ViewModel);

    }
```

I've put a breakpoint in my Index_AddSearchCriteria that is never hit even when I press on the Search button.

I've got jquery and unobtrusive-ajax loaded.

EDIT:
this is the error I get --

```
POST http://localhost:51989/Home/Index_AddSearchCriteria 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.8.2.js:8430
send jquery-1.8.2.js:8430
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.js:7982
asyncRequest jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:121
(anonymous function) 
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:171
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.2.js:3077
```

elemData.handle.eventHandle

EDIT 2:
So the code does work, but I also have another PartialView on the same page that's using Ajax and polling every 100ms, which seems to make it take a long time to send the search query. I've change it to 1000ms and the search works fine.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools or use a program like fiddler to see if the ajax request is actually being sent. If it is, you should see the response and any error coming back.

Comment: It's being sent, but I'm getting a 404 error that Index_AddSearchCriteria is not found

Comment: I just ran your code and it ran ok. ( i assume the code is building for you as ViewModel is not defined in the sample you gave so i assume its defined and created somewhere else). Have you been playing around with your routes?

Comment: make sure you've included jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax library on master layout or page and also its value set to True in web.Config to achieve this Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your issue. Basically, you are not doing an AJAX "Get" (hence the POST in the error) you are just doing a standard web post. I was able to fix this issue in the end. It seems that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax has an issue and you need to change the code so that all the ".live" events become ".on" events.

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```

To - (please not there are a few .live events so you should change them all. Also dont reference the min file unless you change that also)

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").on("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```